# Is $f $ constant ? True/false

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the  following statement  true/false ?

let  $f$  be an analytic  function in $\mathbb{C}$.Then  $f$ is constant   if the zero set  of $f$  contains  the  sequence

$$a_n=\begin{cases}n & 4\not\mid n\\1/n & 4\mid n.\end{cases}$$

**My  attempt** : I think this statement is false  .   Here the   sequence   of  zeroes   is   $1,2,3,\frac{1}{4},5,6,7,\frac{1}{8}.........\infty$.

Also,both  $0$  and $\infty $ are limit points  of the set  of zeroes

I think  in this case   we  can not used  idenitity theorem  because  identity theorem  hold if  and only if  the limit  point of zeroes   is $0$ only

But  here $\infty $ is also  the  limit points  of the set  of zeroes

Therefore   this  statement is false

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio  limit point of  zeroes  is $0 \implies  f \equiv 0$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio okay  that  mean $f(a_n)  \equiv 0$. Am i right ?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio  I mean  $f(a_n) \equiv 0$  if  $a_n  = 1/n$  ( 4 divide n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $f\left(\frac1{4n}\right)=0$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{4n}=0$. Therefore, the set of zeros of $f$ has a non-isolated point ($0$), and so $f$ is the null function.

Comment: Thanks you Jose   sir  .But   i have  some  confusion  
  what   about  the other  subsequence  $a_n \to \infty$ if $4\not\mid n$.  I mean  $f(\infty)$  ?

Comment: I don't understand your doubt. Yes, the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ as subsequences which diverge to infinity. So what? It has a subsequence which converges to $0$ and that's enough to solve the problem. Imagine this problem: to prove that, if a natural number $n$ is such that $n>20$, $3\mid n$ and $5\mid n$, then $n$ is a composite number. An answer can be: since $n$ is a multiple of $3$ which is not $3$ itself, then $n$ is a composite number. This answer does *not* use the assumption that $5\mid n$. Is that a problem to you? I hope not. A problem can have assumptions which are not needed.

Comment: okay  got it @Jose Carlos sir